# Raycast to hit mutiple objects with the same script but only decrease the value of the object being hit?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I have 4 objects each with the planthealth script attached, as it is right now this will only affect one of them, I have tried making 4 seperate scripts for each game object but end up getting an error not sure why. I am assuming that is a super bad way to acomplish this so if anyone could help me figure out how to make a raycast distinguish different objects so that the values only increase when the ray is hitting that specific object.

```
 void Ray()
{
    Vector2 downward = rayOrigin.transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.down) * rayDistance;
    Debug.DrawRay(rayOrigin.transform.position, downward, Color.green);
    if (Physics.Raycast(rayOrigin.transform.position, rayOrigin.TransformDirection(Vector2.down), rayDistance, plant))
    {
        print("wew");
        Plant_Health plant = plantRef.GetComponent<Plant_Health>();
        plant.health += 0.25f;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, don't attach that to each GameObject. Attach it to one GameObject only. Maybe, an empty GameObject.

You are currently using the `Raycast` function overload:

```
bool Raycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, float maxDistance, int layerMask);
```

and this has no way to determine which GameObject is clicked. It will simply return true if an Object is clicked.

You have to use one of the functions `Raycast` which gives `RaycastHit` as an output. You can find which Object is hit from here.

```
bool Raycast(Vector3 origin, Vector3 direction, out RaycastHit hitInfo, float maxDistance, int layerMask);
```

You can check the GameObjects hit by name:

```
RaycastHit hit;
Vector2 downward = rayOrigin.transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.down) * rayDistance;
Debug.DrawRay(rayOrigin.transform.position, downward, Color.green);

if (Physics.Raycast(rayOrigin.transform.position, rayOrigin.TransformDirection(Vector2.down),
    out hit, rayDistance, plant))
{
    if (hit.collider.name == "object1")
    {

    }
    else if (hit.collider.name == "object2")
    {

    }
    else if (hit.collider.name == "object3")
    {

    }
    else if (hit.collider.name == "object4")
    {

    }
}
```

By tags:

```
if (hit.collider.CompareTag("tag1"))
{

}
else if (hit.collider.CompareTag("tag2"))
{

}
else if (hit.collider.CompareTag("tag3"))
{

}
else if (hit.collider.CompareTag("tag4"))
{

}
```

By layer:

```
if (hit.collider.gameObject.layer == yourLayerNum)
```

Or by instance of the transform, gameobject or collider. The way you do it is your choice but I suggest you use **TAGS**.